# AWS SES sending email from Django App fails

Tags: django, amazon-ses

I am trying to send mail with using **SES** and already setup the mail configuration. Now SES running on production mode -not sandbox-. But in Django App, when I try to send mail nothing happens. it's only keep trying to send, no error.

in `setting.py` made the configuration.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'django_ses',
]

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_SES_REGION_NAME = 'ap-northeast-1'
AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT = 'email-smtp.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com'
```

and email method.

```
def send_mail(request, user, emails, subject, path):
  current_site = get_current_site(request)
  message = render_to_string(f"store/emails/{path}.html", {
    "some": "context"
  })

  send_email = EmailMessage(subject, message, "info@mydomain.com", to=emails)
  send_email.send()
```

By the way I already verified the `info@mydomain.com` in SES console. And when I try to send email from the SES console using **send test email** option, I can send without a problem. But in Django App. I can't.

Is there any other settings should I do. Because I can't see any error popping when I try to send mail. It's only keep trying to send. But it can't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AWS SES provides [two types of endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html#region-endpoints): `API` and `SMTP`

You are using SMTP one

```
AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT = 'email-smtp.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com'
```

But `'django_ses.SESBackend'` working with API type.

Try to set:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'
AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT = 'email.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com'
```

If you want to use usual SMTP connection, you probably need to swap current backend with `backends.smtp.EmailBackend` and set [SMTP connection parameters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/#smtp-backend).

Comment: i removed the `django_ses` and changed it to the default smtp. and additioanlly. I added `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = SERVER_EMAIL = '<info@mydomain.com>'` into settings.py I think this was the key point. now it's working.

Comment: @yvi did you set `EMAIL_HOST_USER` and `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD`? If not, that means that you able to send message without authentication, and everyone can use your SMTP for sending emails (spam for example). I'm not familiar with `SMTP` SES endpoint and not sure is my suppose is correct but recommend to check authentication parameters

Comment: yep, I am using user and password as ses credentials. it doesn't work without auth.